# Command working in interactive shell, but not inside script

Tags: sed

I have a text file named `crn.txt` containing text below:

```
9 1 * * 3,6 /opt/testtingtools/kos/bin/cos.sh
55 23 * * * /opt/testtingtools/tqdaily.sh 2>>/opt/toolcheck/extract.err
50 11 * * 6 /opt/devtools/toolbox/toolcheck.sh >>toolcheck.log 2>&1
55 23 * * 5 /opt/devtools/toolbox/reset.sh >>/opt/toolcheck/log/reset.log
56 23 * * 6 /opt/prdtools/tqweekly.sh 2>>/opt/checktool/extract.err
30 11 * * 6 /opt/proadtools/tool.sh >/opt/checkingtools/tool.log 2>&1
```

I need to delete the lines containing a word `testtingtools` and update `crn.txt` so that the output looks like this:

```
50 11 * * 6 /opt/devtools/toolbox/toolcheck.sh >>toolcheck.log 2>&1
55 23 * * 5 /opt/devtools/toolbox/reset.sh >>/opt/toolcheck/log/reset.log
56 23 * * 6 /opt/prdtools/tqweekly.sh 2>>/opt/checktool/extract.err
30 11 * * 6 /opt/proadtools/tool.sh >/opt/checkingtools/tool.log 2>&1
```

I am using the command

```
sed '/testtingtools/d' crn.txt 2>&1 | tee crn.txt
```

It works in bash or the command line, but not inside the script. I am using unix server (sun solaris).

One more command working in linux but not in unix:

```
echo "$(sed '/testtingtools/d' crn.txt)" > crn.txt
```

---

"Not working" means it is not deleting a particular line, it empties the entire file when I use the code inside the script. But when I use the code in command line, it deletes the line containing testting word from `crn.txt`.

Comment: In order to edit your question and accept an answer, you should register *this* account (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/327289/user327289) - it appears you've accidentally created two separate accounts to reply ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/327292/user327292) and [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/327290/user327290))

Answer (score 2):

Solaris `sed` can not do in-place editing.

On Linux, you would have used

```
sed -i '/testtingtools/d' crn.txt
```

The portable way of doing it, which would work on both Solaris and Linux, is

```
cp crn.txt crn.tmp
sed '/testtingtools/d' <crn.tmp >crn.txt &&
rm crn.tmp
```

What's probably happening for you is that `tee` truncates the file before `sed` has a chance of reading from it, resulting in an empty file.  Commands in a pipeline are run concurrently.

In general you'd want to avoid reading from a file that you are truncating in the same command, and instead use a temporary file.  This is what `sed -i` does behind the scenes.

Likewise with your other command:

```
echo "$(sed '/testtingtools/d' crn.txt)" > crn.txt
```

which is better written as

```
sed '/testtingtools/d' crn.txt >crn.txt
```

The *first* thing that would happen in any standard shell (on Linux and on Solaris), is that the shell sees the redirection and truncates the output file to zero size.  *Then* it executes `sed`.  This command would not work as expected on Linux nor on Solaris (if you expect it to edit the original file, that is).

Comment: no `-i` in [Solaris sed](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/sed-1.html)

Comment: I always like to plug [Scott's version of this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549): `cp input_file temp_file  &&  command … temp_file > input_file  &&  rm temp_file` -- and that's what you already did!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Almost, apart from the conditionals. It keeps the permissions/ownerships on the original file.  Actually, the conditionals are not needed as a failure to `cp` the file would result in `sed` not running and the original file being left untouched.  Hmm... a `&&` before `rm` may be prudent however.

Answer (score 0):

```
We can do it both sed and awk
```

awk method

```
awk '!/testtingtools/{print $0}' crn.txt >l.txt &&yes| mv l.txt crn.txt
```

output

```
 cat crn.txt
50 11 * * 6 /opt/devtools/toolbox/toolcheck.sh >>toolcheck.log 2>&1
55 23 * * 5 /opt/devtools/toolbox/reset.sh >>/opt/toolcheck/log/reset.log
56 23 * * 6 /opt/prdtools/tqweekly.sh 2>>/opt/checktool/extract.err
30 11 * * 6 /opt/proadtools/tool.sh >/opt/checkingtools/tool.log 2>&1
```